# "Proceed" or "precede"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

When I use Microsoft Word, it shows me that the word *proceed* is wrong with the following sentence:

> This is the only way I can **proceed** with school

and it corrects it to the following:

> This is the only way I can **precede** with school

Which one is correct?

Comment: I think "proceed" is correct in your sentence. proceed vs. precede: http://grammarist.com/usage/precede-proceed/

Comment: Was it a red squigley or a green squigley? If green, you can disregard as Word doesn't know grammar. If it was a red squigley, then I guess word doesn't know spelling either. *Proceed* is a word.

Comment: @Matt: "Precede" is also a word.  :P

Comment: If license allows and is friendly enough, I would recommend almost any other word processor in existence: http://www.scribus.net/ http://www.libreoffice.org/ http://www.abisource.com/ http://www.jarte.com/ http://documenteditor.codeplex.com/ http://www.lyx.org/ or even http://www.openoffice.org/

Comment: The fact that Word is getting this wrong takes the question out of the realm of general reference.

Comment: @Bobbi Bennett The problem is if (and when) the Web is a general reference, independently from Word functions.

Answer (score 4):

"Proceed" is definitely correct.

"Proceed" means "to continue or go onward" with something esp. after a break. "Precede" means "going before/ahead" of someone/something/place/time.

I don't see how someone can "go before the position of school" in this context, that doesn't make any sense!